# UIInterfaceOrentation on iPad

Tags: ipad

I have an app that is a game, and it does not look or work right in Landscape.

Right now My code is:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Overriden to allow any orientation.
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
```

}

And that allows it only to run in portrait (home button on bottom) and I want it to run in both Portrait's (Home button on bottom OR top) so apple accepts it.

I have tried:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

and it didnt work...
Can someone give me the Code to make it so it runs in both portrait modes.

Answer (score 0):

You can only return once, so the second return statement is never evaluated. Make it a boolean OR:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

There are also macros for portrait and landscape, but this should work just fine.